# Can't change volume in ncmpcpp

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa

Playing and pausing songs in ncmpcpp works but changing the volume doesn't, the current volume shows up as `Volume N/A` and the visualizer doesn't seem to be working as well.

I have a whole bunch of audio systems installed so I am not sure what I am currently running.

This is my mpd config:

```
db_file            "~/.config/mpd/database"

music_directory    "~/music"

auto_update "yes"

playlist_directory "~/.config/mpd/playlists"
pid_file           "~/.config/mpd/pid"
state_file         "~/.local/state/mpd/state"
sticker_file       "~/.config/mpd/sticker.sql"

audio_output {
        type          "alsa"
        name          "ALSA sound card"
}

audio_output {  
type               "fifo"  
name               "fifo_visualizer"
path               "/tmp/mpd.fifo"
format             "44100:16:2"
}
```

Comment: Does this help? [ncmpcpp shows "volume n/a"](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/3n8bdm/ncmpcpp_shows_volume_na/)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix so I think my problem might be that I am using a combination of audio systems that don't behave well with each other, I'll create a new question tomorrow to figure out how to solve that, and then come back to this one and see if that helps